# Hi, Im having a hard time finishing this code in python. I want python to give me a total based on fixed prices of three items bought

Tags: python

So in the code I have fixed prices for hammers, nails, and saws.
Nails are $.50, hammers are $3.00, and saws are $2.50.I want it to ask "how many nails do you want?" "how many hammers do you want?"  "how many saws do you want?"
Then give me a total price based on the input from these three questions. Thank you

Comment: Finishing what code?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you’ve tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Next time please provide an example of what you've already tried so we can help you better. However, what you can do is use the input function in python:

```py
nail_count = input("How many nails? (50 cents each): ")
hammer_count = input("How many hammers? (3 dollars each): ")
saw_count = input("How many saws? (2 dollars 50 cents each): ")
```

Then you can convert all the values to integers and multiply by the price

```py
nails_price = int(nail_count) * 0.5
hammers_price = int(hammer_count) * 3.0
saws_price = int(saw_count) * 2.5
```

Then you can simply print out all the prices added together

```py
print(f"Total price is: {nails_price + hammers_price + saws_price}")
```

However, this code leads to some issues. If the user enters nothing, or if the user enters something that is not an integer count of items, the code fails. To combat this, we must check for an integer every time the user enters a count:

```py
while True: # Loop runs forever until user enters an integer number of nails
    try: # Try-except to check if nail_count will properly convert to an integer or not
        nail_count = input("How many nails? (50 cents each): ") # Get count
        nails_price = int(nail_count) * 0.5 # Convert count to price
        break # Break out of the while loop if it worked
    except ValueError: # Catch a value error if it didn't work
        continue # Just let the loop continue
# Repeat above code for hammers
while True:
    try:
        hammer_count = input("How many hammers? (3 dollars each): ")
        hammers_price = int(hammer_count) * 3.0        
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
# Repeat it again for saws
while True:
    try:
        saw_count = input("How many saws? (2 dollars 50 cents each): ")
        saws_price = int(saw_count) * 2.5
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

# Print out the final sum of prices
print(f"Total price is: {nails_price + hammers_price + saws_price}")
```